# What is the "layers" field of the framebuffer create info for?

Tags: vulkan

If the "layers" member of this struct is 3 for example, and I have an image view attachment in the framebuffer at [0] with three layers, will the shader run three times and will I get an in-shader variable telling me which layer it is?

I know that multi-layer rendering was something available in OpenGL, but the catch is that it only works with a geometry shader. Is this what the "layers" field of the framebuffer create info does?

If I want to write to multiple layers without the geometry shader, what are my options? Does VK_EXT_shader_viewport_index_layer help? I know that VK_KHR_multiview will do this, but just want to find out if it's possible without it.

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#interfaces-builtin-variables-layer

Comment: @krOoze So that field is only for use in a geometry shader? Is there an extension that allows you to write the layer out from the vertex shader, I believe I saw this somewhere. This is quite apart from the multiview extension (something different), which has gl_ViewIndex available in all shaders (vertex, fragment etc.)

Comment: Per the spec, geometry, mesh shader with the appropriate extension, and vertex or TES with `shaderOutputLayer` feature in Vulkan 1.2.